# Automatically decode errors in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Anyone know of a way to automatically decode url encoded errors in the Chrome Developer Tools console window?  Depending on the components in use, some errors are encoded and re-encoded countless times.  Even if you manually decode an error, there's a good chance it will needed to decoded again and again.  Also, it is common for the URL to be so long that it cannot be clicked on.

I'd love to have a Chrome plugin / extension that would...

1. Look for a URL encoded message in the console;
2. Decode the message; and,
3. Repeat 1 & 2, above, until the message is completed decoded.

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: To be honest i have never seen something like that... Is it something you are developing? Cause it looks more like there is an issue with your stack if this is how your errors look like...

Comment: Click on the link it produces. Will take you to angular error interpreter OR-- use development version for more verbose message and stack trace output

Comment: Can you include text of the anonymous function which generated the output at Question?